# fsck: dirty bit is set

Tags: linux, ubuntu, filesystems, fsck

This issue began when I force-shutdown my system during an update. After that, I could only boot by changing the boot parameter in grub from "ro" to "rw". Then, every time I boot, when I run fsck, I get the following output.

`0x41: Dirty bit is set. Fs was not properly unmounted and some data may be corrupt.`

What can I do to repair my filesystem?

Answer (score 2):

You probably have a system with UEFI, and the error message is related to the FAT32 filesystem's "dirty bit" on the EFI System Partition (ESP). This partition is usually mounted as `/boot/efi`, but some distributions mount it in a different location (possibly `/boot`) or leave it completely unmounted except when actually updating the kernel and/or bootloader.

Resetting the dirty bit is something `fsck.vfat` (which is also used for FAT32 filesystem) can certainly do. However, some versions of it will need an option to actually write changes to the filesystem. Check the man page of `fsck.vfat` for details applicable to your specific version.

You can simply unmount the ESP filesystem, then check it. Never check any FAT32 filesystem while it's still mounted - otherwise the filesystem driver in the kernel will just overwrite the "dirty bit" again when the filesystem is accessed.

Changing the boot parameter from `ro` to `rw` is very likely hiding another problem your system has. There might be another filesystem needing checking. Perhaps it's your root filesystem?

If the boot process is stopping and leaving you in text-mode command prompt, this is **precisely** to allow you to run a filesystem check for your root partition while regular utilities are not yet allowed to write to it. That is normally the only way to run a filesystem check on the root partition without first booting the system from another media.

If you run a check on your root filesystem and it makes any changes to the filesystem, you should reboot immediately after the check is completed. The kernel may still have some already-read blocks from before the changes cached in memory, and if the root filesystem is remounted write-enabled without rebooting first, it might write those blocks (and the errors within them) right back onto the disk.

Comment: You're right that it's `/boot/efi` because `sudo fsck /boot/efi` shows the dirty bit. However I couldn't get fsck.vfat to work: it just outputs `open: Is a directory`, even if I unmount `/boot/efi` first. Also, could this relate to a non-clean windows shutdown (I have a dual boot). EDIT: I can reset the dirty bit with plain fsck but the error recurs. EDIT: If I remove the dirty bit with plain fsck, unmount, and then remount `/boot/efi` again, the error recurs.

Comment: After unmounting `/boot/efi` you cannot target `fsck` to `/boot/efi` because it is then just an ordinary empty directory on the root/boot filesystem. You'll need to target the corresponding partition instead. For example, if `/boot/efi` is located in the first partition of the first disk (you can check with `lsblk` while it is still mounted), the command would be `sudo fsck /dev/sda1`.

Answer (score 0):

For RHEL 7, I did the following:

To list your disks:

```
df -h
```

or

```
lsblk
```

To unmount the disk you want to repair (in the example below /dev/sda1):

```
umount /dev/sda1
```

To clear the dirty bit and repair the disk:

```
fsck /dev/sda1 -a -w
```

NOTE: The above commands are fsck.vfat which is for fat.  It seems that depending on the file system, a different version of fsck will run and different parameters may be required.   In fsck.vfat, -a is automatic repair and -w is write the changes immediately.

To mount the disk again:

```
mount /dev/sda1
```

To reboot the system:

```
systemctl reboot
```

or just

```
reboot
```